# Appending a vector in R

Tags: r, append

I am trying to write a simple function that takes a random sample from one vector, prints it, and then updates a list of previously printed samples. However, the function I have keeps replacing the previous items. Here is an abstract version of the function:

```
a <- rep(1:10)

b <- vector(length = 0)

fun <- function() {
  s <- sample(a, 1)
  b <- c(b,s)
  
  print(paste("Sample:", s)) 
  print(paste("Selected so far:",b))

}

fun() 

[1] "Sample: 8"
[1] "Selected so far: 8"

fun()

[1] "Sample: 6"
[1] "Selected so far: 6" # should be 8 6
```

any advice? This feels like it should be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<<-` instead of `<-`.

*The operator `<<-` is normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned.*

```
fun <- function() {
  s <- sample(a, 1)
  b <<- c(b,s)
  print(paste("Sample:", s)) 
  print(paste("Selected so far:",b))
}
fun()
#[1] "Sample: 7"
#[1] "Selected so far: 7"
fun()
#[1] "Sample: 3"
#[1] "Selected so far: 7" "Selected so far: 3"
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume to avoid repeating "selected so far:" I could do separate print functions?

Comment: You can try `paste("Selected so far:", paste(b, collapse = ", "))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid super assignment (usually a good idea), you could have you function accept an argument.

```
fun <- function(b) {
  s <- sample(a, 1)
  b <- c(b,s)
  
  print(paste("Sample:", s)) 
  print(paste("Selected so far:",b))
  return(b)
}

b <- fun(b)
b <- fun(b)
```